# How to turn off magnifier in ImageEditing view in Visual Studio 2008? (error?)

Tags: visual-studio-2008

It is a little silly question, however after turn on magnifier, something blocks possibility of using any other tool, in both column/windows with image.

[alt text http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/109/magnifiervs9.jpg](http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/109/magnifiervs9.jpg)

I can't turn off this in any zoom level. Magnifier reacts on clicks left and right mouse button exactly in this same way.

It is very annoying.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the Zoom tool.  It is just the only tool that is available for this image format.  It is a [documented restriction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1dadd79.aspx) in the Visual Studio image editor:

*Using the Image Editor, you can view 32-bit images, but you cannot edit them*

You'll have to either use another graphics editor or switch to a 24bpp image format.